# SEO Strategy for 2 websites selling the same product

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

We currently have 2 websites that are selling the same products (let’s say the same houses in Norway). I am a beginner in SEO and put a lot of effort into optimizing one of them in the last 6 months, mainly by concentrating on writing good content on the topic and carefully doing my keyword research. Now I finally start seeing the results of the hard work and my client came to me with a second domain that sells the **same** houses and represents the same company.

This one hasn’t had much of an optimization going on and it has almost no visitors. In fact, the majority of the pages aren’t even indexed. I just can't see a reason for this site at all. I suppose this domain was bought with the idea that domain keywords are more important than the rest of the URL or the content itself.

My client however prefers using it for easier filtering and management of the real estate listings, but that means (at the very least) making sure to always keep both websites up to date.

I personally would’ve continued investing time and resources into the one domain that is already ranking well and updating it regularly with relevant information, but I wanted to hear a second opinion on this.

Comment: I would suggest you tell your client that building a single, branded and focused website is better than multiple small and cheap sites. I once had a real estate client that had 400 different domains. His rationale was that even if each received 10 visitors per day on each, that meant 4000 visits and therefore, potential customers. The brand was diluted, maintaining that number of sites was a nightmare, and in the long run, it just doesn't make sense. Another competitor run a single website, with all the bells and whistles, and in 6 months, was outperforming and gaining much more visitors.